# Modular OSGI Java Framework for Web?

Tags: java, model-view-controller, web, osgi

I am looking for a powerfull up to date Java OSGI framework for WEB, 
which would allow

- Modular architecture (OSGI)
- Flexible Views (JavaScript, HTML, Templates...)
- String MVC separation
- Maybe preimplemented CMS modules?
- Is developed actively and open source

What I found was

- ZEND for PHP. Does the Java world offer something comparable?
- Spring Spliced may be the solution
- Eclipse RAP, can OSGI but does not offer Views which are flexible enough
- ... ?

Comment: As currently Apache Felix and Eclipse Equinox are the most upto date OSGi frameworks available, personally I am using Felix and it works best.

Comment: As a matter of opinion I have had great difficulty practically using OSGi. It was a nightmare and I spent an incredible amount of time resolving version dependencies when no conflict should of existed to begin with.

Comment: @PradeepSimha however those are just osgi containers. It doesn't resolve the question which app servers, which frameworks should be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm quite fond of [Vaadin](https://vaadin.com/home), it plays nice with OSGi, and it's quite active.
It's a UI toolkit, based on Google GWT.

Mind you, you still have quite some decisions to make: You can use an OSGi framework 'straight up', like Felix or Equinox, but perhaps you'll be better off using an application server, like Apache Karaf or Eclipse Virgo.

Answer (score 3):

Take any std. framework of your choice and deploy it on top of Karaf (if you don't want to hassle with building your own OSGi runtime environment), or if you want to build everything up from scratch take also Pax-Web into account it also supports Servlet 3.0 and OSGi take a look at [the home page of Pax-Web](https://ops4j1.jira.com/wiki/display/paxweb/Pax+Web).

Answer (score 2):

You should look at Apache (Felix) Sling or its commercial version CQ5 (formerly Day Software). It is fully based on OSGi.

Answer (score 2):

I'm developing OSGi based web applications on a daily base. We have a slightly alternative approach which works very well:

- RESTful web services implemented using OSGi services
- Modular AngularJS based user interface, packaged in OSGi bundles

Although AngularJS is obviously not a Java web framework, it fits modern web development perfectly. If you are familiar with Java MVC web frameworks it's also easy to understand Angular.

The main question is how to modularize your code. At the backend we implement everything as OSGi services. RESTful webservices are implemented with JAX-RS using the Amdatu (amdatu.org). With Amdatu you can use JAX-RS in a way that fits OSGi well. Each RESTful resource and lower level services are packaged in separate bundles as well, so the backend is fully modular.

To modularize the UI itself we separate functional different parts of the application as different Angular applications. Each Angular application is packaged in separate bundles as well, using the Amdatu resource provider.

Answer (score 0):

You could test Konekti a Open Source OSGi business platform powered by Eclipse Virgo OSGi Container developed by Thingtrack.

- Vaadin.
- Spring.
- JasperReport.
- Quartz.
- JBoss JBmp, drools.
- Apache Camel, ActiveMQ.
- And many more

http://www.konekti.org